# Android. Is it possible to change part of text in Canvas?

Tags: android, text, canvas

I want to draw text in Canvas. using this code:

canvas.drawText(getString(R.string.test1)+c, 30,320, paint);

a need change of "c" to bold...

Thanks...

Comment: Only c? R.String.test1 is not supposed to be bold?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display multi-color text with one call to Canvas.drawText()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410515/is-it-possible-to-display-multi-color-text-with-one-call-to-canvas-drawtext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the class `Paint` has method `setTypeface` , you can pass a `Typeface`.
code exmaple:

```
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

so if you want change part of text, can draw one by one through change the typeface.

also, you can **try use html code like** `<b>c</b>`

Answer (score 0):

[Canvas.drawText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) and its various variants do all expect either a `String`, `CharSequence` or `char[]`. All those types do not support Spannable or Stylable objects. Short: It's not possible in the way you want.

You probably can try to implement the suggesstions `idiottiger` posted.