# Is it possible to display multi-color text with one call to Canvas.drawText()?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I would like to use Canvas.drawText() to display multi-color text. More specifically, I want to highlight a substring of the text passed to the drawText() method.

The text is in the form of a SpannableString with 0 or more ForegroundColorSpan objects.

Looking at the Canvas code, it appears that a .toString() call on the passed CharSequence, means that this is not possible.

Is there an alternative way?

EDIT: The text may occasionally change (total changes, not incremental). Also, there are potentially multiple texts positioned in different unrelated locations in the custom view.

Comment: Use Shader for multi color text

Comment: Thanks but I cannot see how to achieve this. Which Shader class in particular?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes it is possible by using one of the [Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html) classes. These are helper classes for drawing text to a canvas and they support Spannables. If your text doesn't change use a StaticLayout.

**Example**

Add this to your custom view class

```
private StaticLayout layout;
```

put this code into your `onLayout` or `onSizeChanged`

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers");  

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
paint.setTextSize(20f);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
layout = new StaticLayout(wordtoSpan, paint, getWidth(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);
```

Then in your drawing method simply call

```
layout.draw(canvas);
```

In case your text changes often you can use a `DynamicLayout`.

```
Editable.Factory fac = Editable.Factory.getInstance();
Editable edit = fac.newEditable(wordtoSpan);
DynamicLayout layout = new DynamicLayout(edit,paint,getWidth(),Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,1,0,false);
```

change text by using the edit object

```
edit.append("hello");
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. This looks very promising.  In my case, the text does change. In this case, could some kind of invalidate() call be used to achieve what I want?

Comment: In that case you simply use [DynamicLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html) or create a new layout each time the text changes.

Comment: ok, I will look into this. In fact, I am displaying multiple strings so I suppose one DynamicLayout for each string?  Also, when the text changes, the whole text changes (i.e. it is NOT like text being edited in an EditText). Does this affect the desired solution?

Comment: You could assemble all those strings to one single string 'TextUtils.concat(span1, span2);'

Comment: They are written in seemingly random positions all over the custom view. Exact positioning is essential.

Comment: ok then you need multiple Layouts and use canvas.translate to position them. Are those strings always single line? Then you could use BoringLayouts. If not then I dont know what Layout class should be preferred. Both should be relatively easy to integrate. Its something you would need to test yourself.

Comment: Yes, always single line. I suppose BoringLayout does not support editing the text?  In which case, invalidateLayout() should work?

Comment: invalidateLayout() does not exist. You need to use either DynamicLayouts or create new BoringLayouts for each string. I think we are getting off topic with the comments right now. You should consider creating a new question if you have problems.

Comment: @Renard you seem to know a lot spans. I am trying to set a ReplacementSpan extended class into a StaticLayout but nothing is drawn. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, if you use TextView

```
String multiColorText = "<font color=0xff0000>Multi</font><font color=0x000000>Color</font><font color=0xccffff>Text</font>";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(multiColorText));
```

**Edit :**
For SpannableString, check if the below helps you

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("partial colored text"); 

WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 2, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using a TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you write that text for that view you can set  **thatView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.multicolor);**  and

In **multicolor.xml**  write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <gradient 
            android:startColor="@color/tabBgStart"
            android:endColor="@color/tabBgEnd"
            android:angle="270"/> 
</shape>
```

Hope it will works definitely

To Change the text color you can use **yourView.setTextColor(R.drawable.multicolor);**

Answer (score 1):

i hvn't used in with Canvas. see below code how i used it in textview.

```
public TextView getTextClipArt1(){
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    Typeface tf = new MyTypeface(context, 0).getTypeface();

    Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 30,
            new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE},
            new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);

    textView.setTypeface(tf);
    textView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
    textView.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    textView.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(2);
    textView.setText("ABC");
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    return textView;
}
```

you can now draw textview as bitmap on canvas, Although i think these methods are also exist in paint class.
Hope useful to you.