# Canvas draw html text

Tags: android, canvas, drawtext

Is it possible to pass Html to `Canvas.drawtext()`. 
I tried this:

```
canvas.drawText(Html.fromHtml("This is an <u>underline</u> text demo for TextView."), 0, 20, colIndex, rowIndex, getTextPaint());
```

But that cannot parse tags and not show correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paint already has methods to format the text like under lining, applying the colors... So you can use them to format your text instead of html tags

Comment: Instead of  `drawText` I think you shoul use `Layout.draw()`, it accepts `HTML`, here you are more information about [DynamicLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html)

Comment: @Chandrakanth  tnx for answer, Can u provide an example?

Comment: @Skizo tnx, But what is Layout in this case?

Comment: @Naruto I'm not sure if there's a simpler way, but I just ran a test that loaded some HTML in an off-screen WebView to render it, then drew the WebView to a Canvas. Might be a usable workaround, if you don't find a better way.

Comment: @MikeM. tnx. but I have some problem with `WebView`. It cannot support arabic letters.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki Interesting. I was not aware of that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: As mentioned in the above comments, we may use Dynamic or Static Layout. Instead of String we need to use Spannable text. This can handle html tags. You may find the example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10410843/2641380

Answer (score 4):

You can parse the html string into `Spanned`

```
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html, int flags) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(html, flags);
    } else {
        return Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
}
```

then use StaticLayout to draw:

```
mStaticLayout = new StaticLayout(fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), mPaint, sizeWidth, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0, false);
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want under line text then you can write like this

```
    TextPaint textPaint=new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    textPaint.setFlags(TextPaint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawText("Hello", 0, 20, textPaint);
```

Comment: I want no only underline, I want support all supported tag, like <div> <br> <small> <sup> etc... . In my case I passed a full html content to that, which have multiline and multi tag.